# Postgres - Difference between SELECT function() and CALL function()?

Tags: postgresql, function, postgresql-11

In PostgreSQL v11,
Difference between SELECT function() and CALL procedure?
If I select a procedure this errore is returned:

ERROR: public.delete() is a procedure
To call a procedure, use CALL.

Comment: What about the error message or behavior surprises you?

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, usually I use SELECT statement, not CALL

Comment: there is a difference between sql functions that can be used for example in select clauses, these simply format or manipulate the selected column data. Stored procedures on the other hand cannot be selected only called as they are not functions but procedures (which have side-effects and so on..)

Comment: see here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194684/in-postgresql-what-is-the-difference-between-a-stored-procedure-and-other-typ, and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2357/what-are-the-differences-between-stored-procedures-and-stored-functions

Comment: `select` is for functions, `call` [is for procedures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-call.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure can not be SELECTed. Note following basic difference between procedure and function.

```
 - In PostgreSQL 11, PROCEDURE was added
 - Functions return value but procedures does not return values
 - Transaction can be crated inside procedure and not inside function
```

Comment: `Transaction can be crated inside procedure and not inside function` - I don't get what do you mean, in function there is possible creating transaction.